# Tensorflow Float16 for VGG19 model parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing [neural style transfer](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/style_transfer) using TensorFlow(with the 19.01 Nvidia TensorFlow Docker image) in Python. I have an Nvidia 2070 graphics card, and I've been getting Out of Memory errors when I try to run a newer version of the TensorFlow docker image(19.08 for example). So I decided that perhaps it is time to consider using 16 bit precision instead of 32 bit for storing the parameters of the VGG19 CNN.

My initial research when I built my machine had led me to believe that switching from 32 to 16 was a cakewalk, but that hasn't been my experience now that I'm actively trying to make the transition.

This is what I have done:

1. I set tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float16')
2. Set tf.keras.backend.set_epsilon(1e-4)
3. Change my image input to the VGG19 network to a float16, and any other miscellaneous parts of my code that use the float32 datatype in conjunction with the float16.

When I run the code, nvidia-smi still reports that essentially 100% of my GPU is being used. Has anyone had any success with reducing their model memory footprint by switching to float16 in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow has various ways of managing mixed precision. The most suitable mixed precision approach depends on which optimizer you plan to use. Keras optimizers, for example, have an [API designed to easily port code one way or the other](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision). It is called `mixed_precision`.

If you are using a TFv1 optimizer, or one of the other non keras optimizers offered by TensorFlow, you can use their [graph rewrite function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/experimental/enable_mixed_precision_graph_rewrite) to convert various pieces of the graph to float 16.